# PHP Check User login in a new machine or changes of ip address

Tags: login-script

I want to put a protection about user login in different machine or ipaddress.
Like when you log in on facebook they need confirmation on mobile or email when you used new machine or ip address.

How to check or detect this logins?

thank you.

Comment: Your question is wrongly tagged, replace login-script (doesn't mean what you think) with php or something.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're using a common database system like mySQL.
Create a table (like "users_machines") that will store a user id and a machine IP.

Step by step :

**1)** User subscription / first login :

Get the user IP (`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`)
Insert user_id and his IP in the users_machines table.

**2)** Next login :
Get the user IP.

Search in users_machines if there is a corresponding row for this user_id and machine_ip

*There is a corresponding row* : User is still on the same machine. Do nothing.

*There is no corresponding rows* : User is using a different machine.

Block the connection, save a secret token in session and send him a mail with that token hidden in a button.

**4)** User clicks on that button, check if the secret token is valid.

*If it's not valid*, stop and redirect to wherever you want.

*If it's valid*, insert that new IP into users_machines.